# In C/C++ mode in Emacs, change face of code in #if 0...#endif block to comment face

Tags: regex, emacs, aquamacs, emacs-faces

I'm trying to add functionality found in some other code editors to my Emacs configuration, whereby C/C++ code within #if 0...#endif blocks is automatically set to the comment face/font.  Based on my testing, *cpp-highlight-mode* does something like what I want, but requires user action.   It seems like tying into the font-lock functionality is the correct option to make the behavior automatic.

I have successfully followed examples in the GNU documentation to change the face of single-line regular expressions.  For example:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda ()
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil
      '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\|TODO\\|HACK\\|fixme\\|todo\\|hack\\)" 1 
        font-lock-warning-face t)))))
```

works fine to highlight debug related keywords anywhere in a file.  However, I am having problems matching #if 0...#endif as a multiline regular expression.  I found some useful information in this post ([How to compose region like "<?php foo; bar; ?>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507743/how-to-compose-region-like-php-foo-bar)), that suggested that Emacs must be told specifically to allow for multiline matches.  But this code:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda ()
    '(progn
      (setq font-lock-multiline t)
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil
        '(("#if 0\\(.\\|\n\\)*?#endif" 1
          font-lock-comment-face t))))))
```

still does not work for me.  Perhaps my regular expression is wrong (though it appears to work using *M-x re-builder*), I've messed up my syntax, or I'm following the wrong approach entirely.  I'm using Aquamacs 2.1 (which is based on GNU Emacs 23.2.50.1) on OS X 10.6.5, if that makes a difference.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even if you got the multiline regexp to work, you'd still have problems with nested `#ifdef/#endif`'s since it would stop font-locking at the first `#endif`.  This code works, although I'm not sure if there will be a noticeable slow down for large files:

```
(defun my-c-mode-font-lock-if0 (limit)
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((depth 0) str start start-depth)
        (while (re-search-forward "^\\s-*#\\s-*\\(if\\|else\\|endif\\)" limit 'move)
          (setq str (match-string 1))
          (if (string= str "if")
              (progn
                (setq depth (1+ depth))
                (when (and (null start) (looking-at "\\s-+0"))
                  (setq start (match-end 0)
                        start-depth depth)))
            (when (and start (= depth start-depth))
              (c-put-font-lock-face start (match-beginning 0) 'font-lock-comment-face)
              (setq start nil))
            (when (string= str "endif")
              (setq depth (1- depth)))))
        (when (and start (> depth 0))
          (c-put-font-lock-face start (point) 'font-lock-comment-face)))))
  nil)

(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '((my-c-mode-font-lock-if0 (0 font-lock-comment-face prepend))) 'add-to-end))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

**EDIT:**
Take into account `#else`

**EDIT #2:**
Niftier code to handle arbitrary nesting of if/else/endif's

Comment: I added 'else' as another keyword to stop the comment face at.  So the one line becomes: (while (and (> depth 0) (re-search-forward "^\\s-*#\\s-*\\(if\\|endif\\|else\\\)" limit 'move)) .  Also, for small files (< 100-200k) the slowdown is minimal.  On a larger file (4.3MB) it is noticeable -- but I don't often edit files that large.

Comment: @pogopop77: Handling `#else` is a little trickier than what you did, so I updated the code.  It doesn't work on an `#if 0` inside the `#else` of an `#if 0`, but I'll probably update it later.  Also: 200k is a small file? ;)

Comment: Updated for arbitrary nesting.  And it's simpler which is always a positive sign :)

Comment: Works great.  I guess I considered any code I'm working on "small" :).  I used the SQLite amalgamated C file as my torture test.

Comment: This works awesome! Anybody have the elisp experience to make it handle #if 1   #else #endif code?