# change color of code within #if 0 ... #endif block in C/C++ mode in Emacs 21.3.1

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

With reference to the link,
[In C/C++ mode in Emacs, change face of code in #if 0...#endif block to comment face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549015/in-c-c-mode-in-emacs-change-face-of-code-in-if-0-endif-block-to-comment-fa).

I tried the code but it doesnot seem to be working. My emacs version is GNU Emacs 21.3.1 on Linux.

Please can you let me know where I am going wrong.

TIA

Comment: That's a really old version of Emacs.  Can you upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

`cpp-highlight-mode` can be made to work without user interaction.  This is how I have mine set up:

```
(defun cpp-highlight-if-0/1 ()
  "Modify the face of text in between #if 0 ... #endif."
  (interactive)
  (setq cpp-known-face '(background-color . "dim gray"))
  (setq cpp-unknown-face 'default)
  (setq cpp-face-type 'dark)
  (setq cpp-known-writable 't)
  (setq cpp-unknown-writable 't)
  (setq cpp-edit-list
        '((#("1" 0 1
             (fontified nil))
           nil
           (background-color . "dim gray")
           both nil)
          (#("0" 0 1
             (fontified nil))
           (background-color . "dim gray")
           nil
           both nil)))
  (cpp-highlight-buffer t))

(defun jpk/c-mode-hook ()
  (cpp-highlight-if-0/1)
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'cpp-highlight-if-0/1 'append 'local)
  )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'jpk/c-mode-hook)
```

The key is figuring out that `cpp-highlight-mode` looks at `cpp-edit-list`.  I set things up the way I wanted the interactive way and then looked at the `cpp-edit-list` that resulted with `C-h v`.

Comment: Nice!  What is the first element in each sublist of `cpp-edit-list` for? The doc only describes that as a string, but you seem to use it for more (e.g., `#("1" 0 1 (fontified nil))`).

Comment: I think what I have in the answer is copy-pasta.  And I don't have that function in my init.el anymore for some reason.  But the doc says it's a 4 element list: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/cpp.el#L92

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it's a four element list, but the first element should just be a string, not `#("1" 0 1 (fontified nil))`.  Now granted, it does work, but I'm perplexed by this!

Comment: That first element might be a fancy fontified string.  Which apparently can be used as a regular string in this context.  E.g. try using `buffer-substring` on a buffer with colored text.  Like I said, this was copy pasta, it might be better if it was just a plain string.