# How to highlight #ifdef <code/> #endif in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet, cc-mode

I don't know if cc-mode or cedet is providing something alike that but that must not be such hard to realize I hope.

What I want is to change background for code in C++ / C# source files between #ifdef (something) and #endif. Is there mode option for make it or where from to start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ mode in Emacs change color of code within #if 0 ... #endif block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189742/c-c-mode-in-emacs-change-color-of-code-within-if-0-endif-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'hideif' package which you can enable with:

```
M-x hide-ifdef-mode
```

After you enable it, you need to customize hide-ifdef-shadow to be true to indicate coloring instead of invisible text.

If you use CEDET to parse your files, you will gain the added benefit of many of your #define macros being accurate with hideif too.