# Replacing text in buffer view

Tags: emacs

In emacs I can replace `function (` with `#(` in javascript with the following.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'js2-mode `(("\\(function *\\)(" ;; \\(function *\\
              (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "#") ;;ƒ
                        nil)))))
```

It's neat. But how would go about making the replacement `# (` or something like `fn (`.

I've tried hacking away at this to understand it... but not yet.

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in folding what's there and placing an overlay instead?  Font-lock is not going to hide and replace.  Or, do you want to permanently replace the text within the file.

Comment: I don't want to permanently change the text in the file. Just how it is rendering to the buffer. The above example is great... but it only replaces the found text with a single character. It would be great to replace it with more than one char.

Comment: The folding and overlay sounds good. _Away to google..._

Comment: It looks like I may have spoken too soon -- here is a link to an example of using `compose-region`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4513933/2112489  So, it appears there are more than one way to handle this type of issue.

Comment: Yeah. The linked example similarly replaces all the php content with a single character...